# GWT Upload doesn't Work After Deploying the Application on TomCat

Tags: tomcat, gwt, file-upload

I have a GWT application which has an upload feature, and it works fine on my eclipse. However, it doesn't work after I deployed the application on Tomcat server. It gives the following error:

"Unable to auto submit the form, it seems your browser has security issues with this feature.
 Developer Info: If you are using jsupload and you do not need cross-domain, try a version compiled with the standard linker?"

My .war lib folder has the needed jars.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Problem could be missing the jar files in the war. Keep your all upload related jar files in the WEB-INF/lib folder and try again. I faced this problem sometime before.

Comment: Thanks Mayilarun! I made sure and the issue still exists  :(

Comment: I used to face this issue because of mishandling the jar files. In development mode in eclipse you may referring the other jar files(could be a chance). Cross check your classpath against the your deployed library(version).

Comment: i checked and still having the same issue. it is really annoying when the error message doesn't help... :(